# How does one get 5 points in a football game?

Tags: american-football, scoring

During today's Niners vs Seahawks game, the score by the end of the first half was 0-5.

What I don't understand is how the Seahawks scored 5 points. My understanding of football is :

- 6 points for a touchdown

  - 1 point for following field goal
  - 2 points for following conversion
- 3 points for regular field goal

In no way can I see a possibility where 5 points would be the combination of any of above said criteria.

Am I thinking something wrong? How is it possible to have 5 points only?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can also get 2 points for a [safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety_%28gridiron_football_score%29), when the offensive team commits an infraction or is tackled in their own end zone. In addition to scoring 2 points, the defending team also receives the ball via a free kick. They are rare, but there have already been a few this season.

So these are the possible ways to score:

1. Touchdown - 6 points
2. Field Goal - 3 Points
3. Two Point Conversion* (following a touchdown) - 2 points
4. Safety - 2 points
5. Point After Touchdown* (field goal-style kick) - 1 point
6. (NCAA, and NFL as of 2015) Blocked extra point try (or any turnover on a PAT or 2-point conversion) is run back - 2 points for defense.
7. Extra point attempt that results in a safety for either side - 1 point

In the game you are referencing, there was a safety and then a field goal, resulting in a 5 point score for Seattle.

*A Two Point Conversion or a Point After Touchdown can only be attempted immediately following a scored touchdown. The team must choose to attempt one or the other.

Comment: The only score that is mathematically impossible in American football is 1.

Comment: @BenMiller: That's only impossible in the NFL; NCAA football allows a score of 1 in a very rare case, left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: @MichaelMyers I assume you're referring to the one-point safety. But it is only awarded when the defensive team recovers the ball and suffers a safety in their own end zone. But it is conditional on the offensive team attempting either a PAT or 2 point conversion, so there will already be 6 points on the scoreboard.

Comment: Also, one-point safeties are possible in the NFL, but there hasn't been one since 1940 (according to this blog article: http://blogs.wsj.com/dailyfix/2013/01/04/2013-fiesta-bowl-oregon-kansas-state-one-point-safety/ ). But the NFL rulebook definitely allows for it (Section 3 Article 2 (d))

Comment: @Leatherwing: That's interesting in light of Article 2 (c), which prevents the defense from e.g. intercepting a pass and retreating into the end zone. The WSJ article says that the only way would be to bat the ball out of the end zone without taking possession, but it's also possible, according to Section 3 Article 3 Item 4(a), for a defensive penalty to result in a one-point safety. I'm not sure how that could happen to a team without possession.

Comment: @MichaelMyers Very interesting.  So it looks like in NCAA the one-point safety could theoretically be scored by either side.  However, in NFL, the play is dead as soon as the defense takes possession, so it is impossible for the defense to score a one-point safety, and therefore impossible to get a score of 1.

Comment: FWIW for high school football, the National Federation of State High School Associations Football Rules state in 8-1 that a forfeited game where the offended team is not ahead shall end with a game score of 1-0.

Comment: Maybe it should be pointed out that the ONLY way to get to five points is via safety and field goal, with no other scoring up to that point.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet That is the only way to have a 0-5 score, as in the original question. But it is possible  for other scenarios where Team A has only 5 points, but Team B has 6. While also confusing, it results from Team B scoring a touchdown, going for the 2-point conversion but Team A intercepts and scores (for 2 points) then later scores a field goal (for 3 points).

Comment: @Leatherwing - after last week's events, you'd think I would have been on top of that scenario!

Comment: @PoloHoleSet This question is over 3 years old and needs to be relevant regardless of the most recent weeks events.

Comment: @Leatherwing - It would be relevant, regardless, but since there was a game decided by a returned 2-point conversion attempt just last weekend, you'd think my comment would have been more accurate.