# NCAA Football 1 Point

Tags: rules, american-football, collegiate, scoring

I heard that is possible to get 1 point in an NCAA football game. Can someone explain how that is possible? I believe it is called the **"One Point Safety"**.

Comment: Related question: https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3546/one-point-safety-by-defending-team?rq=1

Comment: Yeah, that's a duplicate, nice catch.  Though Ben's answer is only partially correct.

Answer (score 2):

You score one point for an extra point try that results in a safety (for either team).  See [this article](http://deadspin.com/5973048/only-two-one-point-safeties-have-ever-happened-in-ncaa-football-history-and-brad-nessler-called-them-both) for example.

Note that in the most recent example of this (the 2013 Fiesta bowl), the one point was actually scored by the team which had just scored a touchdown (so it didn't look particularly odd on the score board).

See the [NCAA Rulebook](http://www.ncaapublications.com/productdownloads/FR12.pdf), section 8-1-1 and 8-1-3.

8-1-1:

> Scoring Plays
>
> > ARTICLE 1. The point value of scoring plays shall be:
> >
> > - Touchdown — 6 Points
> > - Field Goal — 3 Points
> > - Safety (points awarded to opponent) — 2 Points
> > - Successful Try:
> > - Touchdown — 2 Points
> > - Field Goal or Safety — 1 Point

8-1-3 is below:

> SECTION 3. Try Down
>   How Scored
>
> > ARTICLE 1. The point or points shall be scored according to the point
> >     values in Rule 8-1-1 if the try results in what would be a touchdown, safety 
> >     FR-78 Rule 8 / Scoring
> >     (Exception: Rule 8-3-4-a) or field goal under rules governing play at other
> >     times (A.R. 8-3-1-I-II; A.R. 8-3-2-I-III and VI; and A.R. 10-2-5-X-XV).
> >     Opportunity to Score
> >
> > ARTICLE 2. A try is an opportunity for either team to score one or two points
> >     while the game clock is stopped after a touchdown. It is a special interval in the
> >     game which, for purposes of penalty enforcement only, includes both a down
> >     and the “ready’’ period that precedes it.
> >
> > > a. The ball shall be put in play by the team that scored a six-point touchdown.
> > >       If a touchdown is scored during a down in which time in the fourth period
> > >       expires, the try shall not be attempted unless the point(s) would affect the
> > >       outcome of the game.
> > >
> > > b. The try, which is a scrimmage down, begins when the ball is declared ready
> > >       for play.
> > >
> > > c. The snap will be midway between the hash marks on the opponent’s threeyard
> > >       line or from any other point on or between the hash marks on or behind
> > >       the opponent’s three-yard line if the position of the ball is selected by the
> > >       team designated to put the ball in play before the ready-for-play signal. The
> > >       ball may be relocated after a charged timeout to either team unless preceded
> > >       by a Team A foul or offsetting fouls (Rules 8-3-3-a and 8-3-3-c-1).
> > >
> > > d. The try ends when:
> > >
> > > > 1. Either team scores.
> > > > 2. The ball is dead by rule (A.R. 8-3-2-IV and VI).
> > > > 3. An accepted penalty results in a score.
> > > > 4. A Team A loss-of-down penalty is accepted (Rule 8-3-3-c-2).
> > > > 5. Before a change of team possession, a Team A player fumbles and the
> > > >            ball is caught or recovered by any Team A player other than the fumbler.
> > > >            There is no Team A score (A.R. 8-3-2-VIII).

Comment: Your first sentence has it backwards: the ball has to be returned to *the wrong endzone*, which would normally be a two-point safety. And it doesn't matter whether it was a blocked kick or a two-point try.

Comment: @MichaelMyers Okay, rereading in more detail I think you're right.  Nevermind.