# What are the possible outcomes after a blocked extra point in college football?

Tags: rules, american-football, collegiate

I was watching a Div. I NCAA football game today.  A PAT was blocked and one of the defenders picked the ball up.  The announcer said that it was a live ball.

What are the possible outcomes in this situation?  I believe in the NFL that once a PAT is blocked, the ball is dead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [One-point safety by defending team](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3546/one-point-safety-by-defending-team)

Comment: The accepted answer on that question does not answer my question.
I would like to know all possible outcomes in the event of a blocked extra point attempt.

Comment: "I believe in the NFL that once a PAT is blocked, the ball is dead." No longer true based on changes to extra-point rules this season (http://www.nfl.com/news/story/0ap3000000493347/article/nfl-moves-extra-point-to-15yard-line-for-2015-season).

Comment: I'll be darned like socks. You learn something every day. It would seem I can assume this to be true for NCAA too. I'd still like to know if that is every outcome for a blocked extra point.

Comment: Also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-point_conversion#Defensive_two-point_conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ball is in the field of play, it is now a live ball. The defending team can pick it up and run it all the way back for a 2 point conversion. Same thing counts for fumbles and interceptions.

First time it happened when the college rule changed was Kansas State beat Indiana State on a 2 point interception return. https://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1290&dat=19910908&id=STBUAAAAIBAJ&sjid=Do0DAAAAIBAJ&pg=3020,3347106&hl=en

Comment: The rule was introduced in 1988 for NCAA competitions, and Rice scored against Notre Dame in that year. http://www.footballfoundation.org/News/NewsDetail/tabid/567/Article/50946/this-week-in-college-football-history-oct-30-nov-5.aspx